# How can I nest 2 promises and have ionViewCanLeave wait for the outcome?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, promise

I have an Ionic 2 app that uses the `ionViewCanLeave()` navGuard to show a confirmation message.  This works fine; the user is shown a confirmation dialog and can choose to not leave if they want.  Here's the code for it:

```
  // About to leave
  ionViewCanLeave() { 
    if(!this.allowedToLeave) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Are you sure?',
          message: 'Are you sure?',
          buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',
            handler: () => {
              this.allowedToLeave = true;
              resolve();
            },
          }, {
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: () => {
              reject();
            }
          }],
        });
        confirm.present(); 
      });
    }
  }
```

I now need to check an additional variable here from `storage`.  In order to get that variable I need a promise.  My code is as follows:

```
  // About to leave
  ionViewCanLeave() {
    this.storage.get('safe_to_leave').then((val) => {
      this.safeToLeave = val;

      if(!this.allowedToLeave && !this.safeToLeave) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            message: 'Are you sure?',
            buttons: [{
              text: 'OK',
              handler: () => {
                this.allowedToLeave = true;
                resolve();
              },
            }, {
              text: 'Cancel',
              handler: () => {
                reject();
              }
            }],
          });
          confirm.present(); 
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

What happens here though, is that the page is popped from the navigation stack and then the confirmation dialog is shown.  It looks like `ionViewCanLeave()` is not waiting for the storage call to run, as it's asynchronous.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Not related to your question: are you sure the `if` condition is correct? Should it not be an `||` instead of an `&&`? Just guessing by the names of the variables...

Comment: i just want to say that your question helped me in preventing page leave using an alerCtrl, a problem that took me 4 days to solve, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the promise:

```
return this.storage.get( /* ...etc
^^^^^^                             */
```

Comment: Of course... that's sorted it.  Can't believe I missed it :(

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at queuing promises, using the Promise.all() method.

More info at [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
let promises = [];

promises.push(asynchroniousFunction);
promises.push(AnotherAsynchroniousFunction);

Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  console.log('Data from first method', results[0]);
  console.log('Data from second method', results[1]);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error from first method', error[0]);
  console.log('Error from second method', error[1]);
});
```